# getting rid of copy button and header/footer in datatables

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

Hi I was wondering if anyone could help me with this problem.  I am trying to get rid of the header/footer for my datatable shown in picture but I cant seem to get rid of it even with all the help online.  Here are the options for my table
[image]

```
this.dataTableOptions = {
                    aoColumns: [
                            { mDataProp : 'AccountId',          sTitle : 'accntId',           sWidth: '0px',   bSortable : false,   bVisible : false },
                            { mDataProp : 'CampaignId',         sTitle : 'campId',            sWidth: '0px',   bSortable : false,   bVisible : false },
                            { mDataProp : null,                 sTitle : '',                  sWidth: '5%',    bSortable : false,   sDefaultContent : ''},
                            { mDataProp : 'AccountName',        sTitle : 'Account',           sWidth: '20%',   bSortable : true},
                            { mDataProp : 'CampaignName',       sTitle : 'Campaign',          sWidth: '20%',   bSortable : true},
                            { mDataProp : null,                 sTitle : 'Analysis',          sWidth: '60%',   bSortable : false,   sDefaultContent : ''}
                    ],
    //                sDom: 't',
                    bDestroy: true,  
                    bStateSave: false, 
                    bAutoWidth: false,
                    bFilter : false,
                    bLengthChange : false,
                    bInfo : false,
                    bPaginate : false,
                    oLanguage: {
                        sZeroRecords: 'No campaigns matched your search criteria',
                        sEmptyTable: 'No campaigns were found in the specified account'
                    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where the copy button comes from. This seems to be related to a [plugin](http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/) you shouldn't use (it uses flash and will destroy your layout for any user that has a flashblocker installed).

With your settings and the default css applied no head or foot should appear.
See this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aptUMWNGKO412XydX8XE?p=preview).

If you want to get rid of tHead you should simply set it to display:none

```
<thead style="display:none">
```

Maybe show us your full options code and which css you are using.